# How to configure Hadoop (and HBase) dependencies within Visual Studio Code on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, maven, hadoop, visual-studio-code

I have Hadoop 2.9.0 and HBase installed and configured on a Linux Mint. I can browse to Hadoop dashboard and cluster and the service is running - no issues.

Trying to compile some basic Java tutorial with Visual Studio Code to check if a table exists in HBase:

```
Boolean outcome = false;
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
HBaseAdmin hbAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(config);
outcome = hbAdmin.tableExists("tableName");
```

and I'm getting HBaseConfiguration "cannot be resolved". Note that Java and Java Extensions are installed and configured correctly for Visual Studio Code. I used Maven to generate the project - a simple quick-start Java project (which compiles successfully without the Hadoop bit).

I know the issue is around dependencies (I have seen posts about issues like this for Eclipse) but I could not figure out how to resolve it. I tired to add the dependencies manually to pom.xml with no luck.If you can please help with simple clear steps on how to resolve the dependencies that will be great.

Note I got Hadoop installed on "[Home]/hadoop-2.9.0" (so all the jars required are within that path in the relevant subfolders). Thank you in advance.

Here is the POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>MyAppGroup</groupId>
<artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>MyApp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Hadoop jars do not include hbase, and maven won't automatically read that folder.  Please post your POM here

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007. I have added the POM.

Comment: Okay, you have no dependencies at all in there except junit, so why are you confused that you get classes that cannot be resolved?

Comment: Okay, yes, as I mentioned I tried to add those manually but that didn't really work. This is the cleaned up POM. So, I guess the question now is how to add these?

Comment: Add what? Have you tried searching here for Hbase client? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase

Comment: Asking for such resources is off topic for Stackoverflow, sorry

Comment: Hi @cricket_007. Thanks for your replies. Obviously I'm missing the basics here (I'm trying to learn how to do this for the first time), so please bear with me. I followed this for installation: [link] (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html) but I wasn't aware that I need the HBase client. I will give that a go.

Comment: You need the Hbase client, only after you actually have Hbase running. That link is how you install HDFS/YARN, not Hbase, and not how to run Java code against Hadoop or HBase